# PO Box Regex failing on addresses containing the word "box"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Im using the following PO Box regex in a custom jQuery Validate method. Its working in 90% of the cases, but if someone types "21 box hill" - it thinks its a po box and matches.

What do I need to change to my regex to make this work?

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("nopobox", function(value, element) {
    return ! /(?:p(?:ost)?\.?\s?[o|0](?:\.|ffice)?)\b|(?:b(?:[o|0]x)|(?:in))\b/i.test(value);
}, "PO Boxes are not allowed.");
```

These are the matches I need:

**Matches:** PO BOX, P.O. Box, Post Office Box, POBOX123
**Non-Matches:** The Post Hill, The Box Road

Comment: Without knowing what cases it is and isn't supposed to hit on, it's hard to suggest a fix. Perhaps you can give us at sample of things it is supposed to hit on (you already gave us one it isn't supposed to hit on)

Comment: Check for digits after the word 'box'? Most addresses that point to an actual box would be "po box 12345"

Comment: And eliminate any with digits before the word box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a pattern that works well:

```
    var pattern = /^[P|p]*(OST|ost)*\.*\s*[O|o|0]*(ffice|FFICE)*\.*\s*[B|b][O|o|0][X|x]\s*(\d.)*/gi;
```